# Missing KeyPress event

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I got new thinkpad and it's missing a <kbd>ContextMenu</kbd> key and has <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> key where <kbd>ContextMenu</kbd> should have been. I remapped it using `xmodmap`.

The problem is, the key is missing `KeyPress` events, only `KeyRelease` events are there. I figured out the keycode is 107 and ran

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 107 = Menu NoSymbol Menu"
```

If I press <kbd>ContextMenu</kbd> ... ehm ... <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, this gets generated as seen by `xev`:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
root 0xb8, subw 0x0, time 19723366, (753,710), root:(761,752),
state 0x10, keycode 107 (keysym 0xff67, Menu), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

As you can see, the `KeyPress` is missing and `KeyRelease`, in its loneliness, is correctly announcing "Menu". It's not entirely broken: when I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, the `KeyPress` is magically there:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
root 0xb8, subw 0x0, time 19800199, (462,314), root:(470,356),
state 0x10, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
root 0xb8, subw 0x0, time 19800349, (462,314), root:(470,356),
state 0x50, keycode 107 (keysym 0xff67, Menu), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
root 0xb8, subw 0x0, time 19800408, (462,314), root:(470,356),
state 0x50, keycode 107 (keysym 0xff67, Menu), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
root 0xb8, subw 0x0, time 19800541, (462,314), root:(470,356),
state 0x50, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

It's usable now, but it's not yet perfect.
Has anybody seen my `KeyPress`?
Where did it go?

Comment: It's possible that something has grabbed the key, although I thought that would also grab the KeyRelease event. It's also possible that the keyboard acts weirdly — some keyboards are a bit peculiar with the PrintScreen and Pause keys. Switch to a text console (Ctrl+Alt+F1), log in and run `showkey`. Press the key, do you see both press and release events or just release?

Comment: @Gilles yup, `showkey` shows both press and release, but the key number is 99 in showkey, unlike the 107 in xev.

Comment: The different numbers are ok: Xorg uses a keycode numbering with an offset from the hardware, Linux uses the hardware value.

Comment: What is your system keyboard configuration? (E.g. language, options)